# Sudmitting a form in another tab or window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension, tabs, form-submit

I have created a javascript chrome extension that uses

**document.querySelector("form").submit();**

in order to automatically submit a form

How can I make it submit it in another window or tab (or the results to open in another window or tab)?